# How to change the icons in Excel quick access toolbar?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel 2013 (32-bit) Windows 7 (32-bit)

I have several macro shortcuts in the quick access toolbar, however Excel has only one type of icon for macro shortcuts, which creates lots of confusion. Is there any way to change the icon? (highlighted in red box)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can change the icons for each macro you have in the Quick access toolbar, for that do this:

1. Click the dropdown menu of the Quick access toolbar and go to **More commands**.
2. Click in the macro you want to modify its icon, then click in the Modify button.
   [image]

   Choose the icon that you want for that Macro, and if you wish you can also change the display name of your Macro in that window.

   [image]

   That's all!

P.S. Excel only lets you choose an icon from its gallery, it's not possible to choose an external icon.

Comment: Jesus, how did i not see that.. Well many thanks bro..